# fundamental group of ribbon knot

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

The ribbon knot is a boundary of self intersecting disk such that the singularity is a self intersection of the disk along an arc. My question is that how to compute the fundamental group of ribbon knot from its ribbon presentation.  The square knot for example has only two ribbon singularities in its ribbon presentation,  how to get the square knot group from that presentation.

Comment: Do you mean instead of just using a Wirtinger Presentation?

Comment: Can we use Wirtinger presentation for ribbon presentation?